# apache camel split() vs. split(body())

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a problem using the split component. I want to split a large xml file to multiple small files. In the small files I want to group 25 elements together. My first Intention was using the following:

```
from(direct:start)
.split().tokenizeXML("SomeElement", 25)
...
```

But then I get this error:

```
SaxParseException: Cannot find the declaration of element 'SomeElement'
```

Then I tried

```
.split(body().tokenizeXML("SomeElement", "*"))
```

And yeah this worked BUT, `split` takes an Expression as parameter, and with the Expression `body().tokenizeXML("SomeElement", "*")` there is no chance to use the grouping feature. So my question is, 
1. Why does `split()` not find the element? 
2. Is there a chance to use the group feature in `split(Expression)`?

Since we are bound to Java 6 we use camel version 2.13.4.

The XML File looks like this (simplified, imagine there are hundreds of SomeElement elements inside MyRootElement)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyRootElement xmlns="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE">
    <SomeElement id="12345">
        <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
    <SomeElement id="23456">
        <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
</MyRootElement>
```

**EDIT:**

OK, after doing the changes suggested by fiw, it works now.

But now my validation fails. While `.split(body().tokenizeXML("SomeElement", "*"))` embeds `SomeElement` within `MyRootElement`, so that I get splitted messages like this:

```
<MyRootElement xmlns="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE">
        <SomeElement id="12345">
            <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
        </SomeElement>
</MyRootElement>
```

`split().tokenizeXML("SomeElement", 2)` does not consider the root element and the namespace, so I get something like this:

```
    <SomeElement id="12345">
                <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
    <SomeElement id="23456">
                <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
```

Naturally if I validate the splitted message against the schema It fails. Because I need the `SomeElements` embedded within the root element `MyRootElement` like this:

```
<MyRootElement xmlns="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE">
  <SomeElement id="12345">
            <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
  </SomeElement>
  <SomeElement id="23456">
            <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
  </SomeElement>
</MyRootElement>
```

Comment: Can you show an example of your xml file?

Comment: Hi fiw, I added a xml snippet to my original Post.

Answer (score 1):

This test of grouping and xml splitting passed for me:

```
public class TestSplitOnXml extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:in")
                    .split().tokenizeXML("SomeElement", 2)
                        .to("mock:out")
                        .end();
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void testSplitting() throws InterruptedException {
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:out");
        mockEndpoint.setExpectedMessageCount(2);

        Exchange exchange = createExchangeWithBody(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("text.xml"));
        template.send("direct:in", exchange);

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
    }
}
```

with this as test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MyRootElement xmlns="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE">
    <SomeElement id="12345">
        <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
    <SomeElement id="23456">
        <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
    <SomeElement id="23456">
        <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
    <SomeElement id="23456">
        <address addressType="mainAddress" street="Test street" zipCode="12345" city="Testcity"/>
    </SomeElement>
</MyRootElement>
```

From this you can see that the split, tokeniseXML and grouping does work. It may be that your xml is just missing `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:THIS:IS:A-NAMESPACE"`